# Converting simple shell to cmd

Tags: windows, shell, cmd, wget

I have a script which gets the public IP address and writes it to my dropbox folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q > /home/lozicd3/Dropbox/IP/ip.txt
```

I want to achieve the same on my windows machines. Does anyone know how to translate it to `CMD`? I've tried `Cygwin` but can I do this without any external tools?

I was reading something about `bitsadmin`.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go:

```
@powershell.exe -Command (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://ipecho.net/plain','C:\Users\myaccount\Dropbox\IP\ip2.txt')
```

Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`wget` for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\wget\folder
wget http://ipecho.net/plain -O - -q > %USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\IP\ip.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it. :) This solution is not "without any external tools" but still +1 for teaching me something new.